# providedIn: 'platform' but with dependencies injected in root

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular9

I have an angular 9 application with service that open a snackbar.
and I have an angular element embedded in my app.
I'm trying to let the angular element use that service, so I injected it in 'platform'.
The problem is that the dependency of that service (MatSnackBar) is provided in MatSnackBarModule which imported in my AppModule, hence I get NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar.

here my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig, MatSnackBarRef, SimpleSnackBar
} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'platform' })
export class ToasterService {

    private ref: MatSnackBarRef<SimpleSnackBar>;
    constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar) { }

    commonConfig: MatSnackBarConfig = {
        duration: 3000,
        verticalPosition: 'top',
        horizontalPosition: 'left'
    };

    error(message: string) {
        this.open(message, 'error');
    }
    success(message: string) {
        this.open(message, 'success');
    }

    private open(message: string, panelClass: string) {
        this.ref = this.snackbar.open(
            message, null, { ...this.commonConfig, panelClass }
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the error I got

```
main.ts:14 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ToasterService -> ToasterService -> ToasterService -> MatSnackBar]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSnackBar!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67430:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81146:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67285:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67295:57)
    at Object.ToasterService_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:296:147)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81382:63)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81134:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81146:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81146:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:98478:33)
```

P.S. this error occure even without the angular element, but also when a regular component injeced that service.
P.S. this error occure only when I'm providing the service in 'platform'. If I'm providing the service in 'root' everything works fine.

Does the feature providedIn 'platform' is not suitable for this situation?
There is any way to bypass this issue?
Anyone know another way to achieve what I'm trying?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you add MatSnackBarModule inside imports array in module?

Comment: Plus you need to add the module to providers array in app.module

Comment: no, it's no that, I'm still getting that error.. notice that if I'm providing the service in 'root' everything works fine.. the error occures when I'm providing the service in 'platform'